# Some Microsoft apps cannot be upgraded, uninstalled or launched

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 Desktop 10586.420, please watch my screen record https://youtu.be/tZrGTll9muY

These 7 Microsoft apps are stuck in my store update list for ever, all of them had exact the same error code in the end 0x80073CF6. The rest of apps have no problem at all.

What is even worse is that I have no way to uninstall them. And all of them crash on launch.

I even tried to uninstalled some of them (e.g. solitaire) by using PowerShell, I got

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AppxPackage *solitairecollection* | Remove-AppxPackage
 Remove-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered. (Exception from  HRESULT: 0x80073CF6)
 NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] b55e1ee7-c8e3-0000-606b-64b5e3c8d101 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID b55e1ee7-c8e3-0000-606b-64b5e3c8d101
 At line:1 char:41
 + Get-AppxPackage *solitairecollection* | Remove-AppxPackage
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo : WriteError: (Microsoft.Micro...__8wekyb3d8bbwe:String) [Remove-AppxPackage], IOException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.RemoveAppxPackageCommand
```

I also followed the instruction from PowerShell output to run another command

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AppxLog -ActivityID b55e1ee7-c8e3-0000-606b-64b5e3c8d101

Time                      ID           Message
----                      --           -------
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     301          The calling process is powershell.exe
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     603          Started deployment Remove operation on a package with main parameter:
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe and
                                       Options: 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help
                                       diagnosing app deployment issues.
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     10002        Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\cc4af31a
                                       -76fe-4a7c-b09c-5ecd7d57b176_S-1-5-21-3042240410-3763251108-3400705136-1001_1.rs
                                       lc for Remove Operation on Package
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     607          Deployment Remove operation on package
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe has been
                                       de-queued and is running for user MYWIN10\hardy.
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     10000        About to service package
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Setting
                                       the package state to disabled returned with 0x0.
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     317          C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x
                                       64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml(45,16): warning: The
                                       'windows.publisherCacheFolders' extension category in the
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe package is
                                       unrecognized.
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     475          error 0x80070002: Reading manifest from location: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windo
                                       ws\AppRepository\Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_neutral_split
                                       .language-zh-hans_8wekyb3d8bbwe.xml failed with error: The system cannot find
                                       the file specified.
                                       .
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     402          error 0x80070003: Reading manifest from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with
                                       error: The system cannot find the path specified.
                                       .
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     322          error 0x80070003: Cannot register the Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9
                                       .5100.0_neutral_split.language-zh-hans_8wekyb3d8bbwe package because the
                                       following error was encountered while trying to read the package: The system
                                       cannot find the path specified.
                                       .
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     300          error 0x80070003: Cannot register the
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_8wekyb3d8bbwe package due to the
                                       following error: The system cannot find the path specified.
                                       .
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     605          The last successful state reached was ResolvedDeferredRegistrations. Failure
                                       occurred before reaching the next state RegistrationChanged.
2016-06-22 8:17:00 PM     10001        Finished servicing package
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Setting
                                       the package state to enabled returned with 0x0.
2016-06-22 8:17:01 PM     401          Deployment Remove operation with target volume C: on Package
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe from:
                                       (Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe)  failed
                                       with error 0x80073CF6. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for
                                       help diagnosing app deployment issues.
2016-06-22 8:17:02 PM     471          error 0x5: Deleting file \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\2FE3CB00.PicsA
                                       rt-PhotoStudio_3.1.0.0_x86__crhqpqs3x1ygc8963b64d-44f3-4302-9dd4-743144b7e144\Cl
                                       rCompression.dll failed.
2016-06-22 8:17:02 PM     471          error 0x91: Deleting file \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\2FE3CB00.Pics
                                       Art-PhotoStudio_3.1.0.0_x86__crhqpqs3x1ygc8963b64d-44f3-4302-9dd4-743144b7e144
                                       failed.
2016-06-22 8:17:02 PM     471          error 0x5: Deleting file \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\2FE3CB00.PicsA
                                       rt-PhotoStudio_3.1.1.0_x86__crhqpqs3x1ygcd826c1bf-b5d6-422b-ae89-f2729efaa392\Cl
                                       rCompression.dll failed.
2016-06-22 8:17:02 PM     471          error 0x91: Deleting file \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\2FE3CB00.Pics
                                       Art-PhotoStudio_3.1.1.0_x86__crhqpqs3x1ygcd826c1bf-b5d6-422b-ae89-f2729efaa392
                                       failed.
```

For each failed app regardless from store app or PowerShell, I can find 2 records in event log

The first one is an error

```
Faulting application name: Solitaire.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x573236e5
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.306, time stamp: 0x571af331
Exception code: 0x00000004
Fault offset: 0x0000000000071f28
Faulting process ID: 0x3b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1cce2da0a558a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Solitaire.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: def6699b-1d13-4e7e-9190-89566b87e8c0
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

The second one is an information

```
Fault bucket 133330737785, type 5
Event Name: MoAppCrash
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
P2: praid:App
P3: 1.0.0.0
P4: 573236e5
P5: KERNELBASE.dll
P6: 10.0.10586.306
P7: 571af331
P8: 00000004
P9: 0000000000071f28
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\hardy\AppData\Local\Temp\WER4C46.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.Micros_d543b85a9693e6ac9dbdf15b55c52c22886f6c5b_234082d4_2315505d

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report ID: def6699b-1d13-4e7e-9190-89566b87e8c0
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 4feeccd86199c8500aed4cec7ded0645
```

Any idea what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized how to fix the issue. If I use GUI (store app) there won't be too much helpful info. But from the behaviours, it is very obvious that store app tries to download the newer version of app, uninstall current version and apply the downloaded version as last step. But unfortunately it failed to uninstall current version.

However when I used PowerShell command `Get-AppxPackage *solitairecollection* | Remove-AppxPackage` as I have pasted in my original question, I got error (the message is also shown in my original question). The error message meanwhile provided another command to load more info. I followed it to retrieve a lengthy report. The result is also in my original question, follow the list the first error encountered was

> error 0x80070002: Reading manifest from location:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_neutral_split.language-zh-hans_8wekyb3d8bbwe.xml
>   failed with error: The system cannot find

I navigated to the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\` directory, indeed the file was not there. But I see `Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe.xml`. I made a copy of this file and named it to `Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_neutral_split.language-zh-hans_8wekyb3d8bbwe.xml` then reran the same uninstall command, it was uninstalled successfully!!!

It looks like Windows 10 messed with the language of the app somehow all of sudden, I guess the system was looking for another language version of the app to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I thought you weren't running the uninstallers with an administrative account, but it turns out Microsoft is blocking you.  If you follow [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-gaming/windows-store-error-code-0x80073cf6/6e87c5d2-f1dd-4c77-a209-d831e06f1165?auth=1) link, state that you must be using a Microsoft account on your Windows machine to install from the MS Store.  If you already are using one, then you may also need to verify your MS account under the Security and Maintenance tab in the control panel.

If you're using a local account instead of a MS account, (which I recommend without hesitation), then I would suggest you create a new account on your PC and give it administrative rights.  After you've finished installing/uninstalling the software that you want, remove the administrative rights and disable the account.  Accounts like that are security flaws in my opinion.

Edit:  They may have made an update so that the password storage uses salted hashes, which ease only some of my problems with a live account.  I'm trying to do a password recovery now to test and see if you can still gain access using access to the PC and the live account.  Give me a few days, my Windows 10 VM for some reason does not like the idea of adding a new user for some reason.

Comment: I installed this version of Windows 10 by completely formatted the hard drive and used my Microsoft account. I don't see lots of settings under Security and Maintenance window, what settings do you refer to?

Comment: Hmmm, try out [this](https://github.com/W4RH4WK/Debloat-Windows-10/blob/master/scripts/remove-default-apps.ps1) script and see if that helps.  Might want to look through what's going to be uninstalled and comment out anything you want to keep before running it though.

Comment: This script is just a wrapper of what I used in my original question.

Comment: Is there anything in this folder: `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/` ?  Also, [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/799e9f97-c448-4cd4-95af-c0619c1afde5/package-could-not-be-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80073cf6?forum=toolsforwinapps) link has an answer near the bottom that's worked for a few people.  You're getting a lot of file not found errors, so it may have removed the apps from the hard drive, but not the registry.

Comment: I cannot claim permission to `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/` folder even I am local admin. I also checked the link you provided, it looks like somebody changed the owner of some registry key to fix the problem. I followed it, `System` is already the owner. There is nothing for me to change.