# Can't remove directory under Windows or Linux

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, permissions

I installed a video game from the the Microsoft Store and all I want to do is uninstall it.
I've tried:

- Uninstalling through the Windows Store. (It won't open and just loads indefinitely)
- Removing the game through the "Add & Remove Programs" dialog. (It fails with an 0x80073cf6 error)
- "Taking ownership" of the directory and deleting it through the command prompt. (Still tells me permission denied).

I figured I could circumvent the Microsoft BS by deleting the folder under linux. Even though I have full permissions on the folder I still get "permission denied" when I try to remove the folder using `rm -rf WindowsApps` as root.

```
# ls -ld WindowsApps
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jun 27 14:09 WindowsApps
```

Am I missing something obvious? I just want to delete a folder. This is taking up 60GB+ on my hard drive and is quite a nuisance.

Comment: After changing owner of a directory, there should be an option box on the bottom to apply to all child folders and files. Something like "replace owner on subcontainers and objects". Then permissions, something like click on permissions tab - leave check box on for "inherit from parent ... " - check box on for "replace permission entries on all child ..." - apply |  "this will ... do you wish to continue?" | yes . Then you should be able to delete the folder and all child objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some Microsoft apps cannot be upgraded, uninstalled or launched](https://superuser.com/questions/1092491/some-microsoft-apps-cannot-be-upgraded-uninstalled-or-launched)